# Post sharing in social network

Tags: social-sharing, sharing

I have a problem. There is AFTER SINGULAR in widgets line. Then I chose widget: text or HTML code.

I have a pictures of 3 social media icons (facebook, twitter, pinterest)

I want that icons (facebook, twitter, pinterest) link will be to :

Example:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=

I want that there would be automatic write post title and post URL.
So, what should I write in the end of the link? (facebook, twitter, pinterest)

Please, help. :-)

Comment: You are asking about the Facebook, Twitter, and Pinterest APIs. This does not have anything to do with WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text widget is only static text widget.

You need to place link to current post on the end of the sharing link (and you have to urlencode it), so I don't think that text widget will help you with your problem.

The easiest solution to your problem will be adding these sharing links in your themes .php file (if you want to place them in sidebar, then sidebar.php would be appropriate file - but it may depend on your theme structure).

Comment: I want add icons after posts.

Comment: After each one of them on list view, or after single post in single post view?

So add these links in correct place (it's hard to say where, because it depends strongly on your theme structure).

Of course you always can use plugin that is adding these links for you (there are many such plugins).

Comment: I know where to add. But what should I write in the end of links? I want to do: then the link is open were will be write: post title and post URL. So, how I should change the end of link?